# Deletion of folder on Amazon S3, while creating external table

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, hive

We are getting very unusual behavior on our S3 Bucket and this behavior is not consistent. So, we are not able to pin point the problem. Now coming to the issue i fire one query(creation of external table). Which leads to deletion of the folder which i was pointing in external table. And this has happened 3-4 time to us. So, could you please explain this behaviour. For you convenience i am attaching the external table query and the logs which operation are being performed on S3 bucket.

Query:

```
create table apr_2(date_local string, time_local string,s_computername string,c_ip string,s_ip string,s_port string,s_sitename string, referer string, localfile string, TimeTakenMS string, status string, w3status string, sc_substatus string, uri string, qs string, sc_bytes string, cs_bytes string, cs_username string, cs_User_Agent string, s_proxy string, c_protocol string, cs_version string, cs_method string, cs_Cookie string, cs_Host string, w3wpbytes string, RequestsPerSecond string, CPU_Utilization string, BeginRequest_UTC string, EndRequest_UTC string, time string, logdate string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\001' location 's3://logs/apr_2_com'
```

logs:

```
 REST.DELETE.OBJECT logs/apr_2_com/000002.tar.gz 
 REST.DELETE.OBJECT logs/apr_2_com/000001.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this syntax -

```
    create external table if not exists apr_2(date_local string, time_local string,s_computername string,c_ip string,s_ip string,s_port string,s_sitename string, referer string, localfile string, TimeTakenMS string, status string, w3status string, sc_substatus string, uri string, qs string, sc_bytes string, cs_bytes string, cs_username string, cs_User_Agent string, s_proxy string, c_protocol string, cs_version string, cs_method string, cs_Cookie string, cs_Host string, w3wpbytes string, RequestsPerSecond string, CPU_Utilization string, BeginRequest_UTC string, EndRequest_UTC string, time string, logdate string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\001' location 's3://logs/apr_2_com'
```

Comment: well thanks for improving the script for creating the hive table. But, i still couldn't figure out why this problem has occured?